# Converting my CSS Units of Measurement from Absolute to Relative

Tags: css

I want to convert my CSS stylesheet units of measurement from Absolute to Relative.

Right now I am using px values. I want to change it over to em.

First of all, I am doing this because I have seen that using em will make the page more versatile for all viewers. Is this the right decision?

If so, how do I go about setting the default value for all others to follow?

Should I put a pixel size for font in the body tag?
Because I usually just assign the background information to the body tag, then I create a div called .whole, and assign the width, etc to that, and everything goes inside of the .whole div instead of just the body container.

So should I put the default value in the body? or should I put it in .whole?

And should I even use em at all? maybe rem, en? or just a mixture of %'s, em, pt's and px, where fit?

This question mainly spawned from checking my css stylesheet against "juicyStudio CSS Analyzer" Since I use px most of the time, the results gave me a bunch of "attention: units are absolute" etc. And shows that guideline 3.4 of the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0, recommend using relative measurements.

Now should I be worried about the set up getting messed up in certain browsers/operating systems or something? Anyway I can test this afterwards to make sure my layout will always stay in sync at different resolutions, browsers, operating systems, etc?

Thanks for your time folks, I appreciate it. 
I know this may be a lot to throw on you guys, hope it isnt too much..

Take Care Everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"2em" means "twice the normal size", or the inhereted size.
The advantage of "em" over "px", is that it's relative to the default/inhereted value.

If I configure my browser to user 16px default size, 2em = 32px.
If you put "20px", it'll be "20px" no matter the user's configuration.

Generally, it's better to use only relative values, since it'll give a look more adapted to the users's configuration/platform.

You should not really specify a "default value", that should be the default the browser assigns.

Comment: Okay then, I see. Now it makes more sense. I guess Ill try to find a good value that is set as the default of most browsers.    Should I not use em's for Width of divs, and what not? should I just focus on using it for fonts mainly?

Comment: I've never used em's for things other than fonts, so I can't really so on that subject.  I've always used percentaje, since it fits no matter the window size/aspect ratio.  But that's more a matter of personal taste, and not so much "because it's the right thing".

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers use scaling over font size changing when client's dpi is different to ordinary.

So using px is OK and you can take advantage of px to make better design.

Comment: It's not a very good practice, because if I configure firefox to use 16px as "default font size, and you set "12px" on your website, the font will be really small for me.  The oposite also applies.

Comment: When design matters, relative units would be a very wrong approach. In this case absolute units would force end user to use a full page scaling rather then changing default font size.

Comment: Full page scaling is not always an alternative.  Portrait monitor, for example, can't scale the entire page, because of the aditional width that would require.  If a small font-size is hardcoded into the page, that's a clear example of who can't see it.